# Aceess make table from a DNS-Less connection

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the below code to create a DNS-Less connection to an Oracle DB and this code works fine. Some information has been removed due to its sensitive nature. Again the posted code is working. I'm looking to add the ability to make a table within access.  How do I take the query results and place them into a table?

```
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim DB As Database


   Set DB = CurrentDb

    'Rem create link to groups def

    Set tdf = DB.CreateTableDef("Sale")
    tdf.Connect = "ODBC;Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=" & ServerName & ";UID=" & UID & ";Pwd=" & PWD & ""
    tdf.SourceTableName = "SBOMAST_OWN.SALE"
    DB.TableDefs.Append tdf
    DB.Close

    Set DB = Nothing
```

Comment: Why is the CommandText ***Empty***?

Comment: I removed my query to remove any sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to make the table from scratch, you will want to use a make table query, which in VBA, takes the form of SELECT * INTO Target FROM Source. I know with ODBC, you can put the connection string directly into the Target and Source values, eliminating the need for a recordset. Your query would become:

```
"SELECT * INTO NewAccessTable FROM (" & strConnectionString & ") OracleDBTable"
```

Check out this article for more information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200427

Comment: Since *Sale* was created in Access as a link to the Oracle table, he should be able to make the new Access table with `SELECT * INTO NewAccessTable FROM Sale;`